# Does $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-nx}d\alpha (x)=\int_{0}^{1} e^{-nx}d\beta (x)$ imply $\alpha (x) = \beta (x)$ in general?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

For $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be monotone non-decreasing continuous real-valued functions with $\alpha (0)=\beta (0)$. The equation $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-nx}d\alpha (x)=\int_{0}^{1} e^{-nx}d\beta  (x)$ holds for any positive integer $n$.

Is $\alpha (x) = \beta (x)$ on $[0,1]$ true in general?

I guess it's not so I'm trying to find a counterexample. I assume $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differential then I get $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-nx}(\alpha '(x)-\beta '(x))dx=0$, I think if we build $\alpha '$ and $\beta '$ wisely, we can make this equation hold(but maybe it can’t hold for every $n$, I feel I’m not on the right way...).

Anyway, I get further equation $e^{-n}(\alpha - \beta)+\int_{0}^{1} e^{-nx}(\alpha (x)-\beta(x))dx=0$. Then I'm stucked here. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continuously differentiable then since $$
\int_0^1 {e^{ - (n + 1)t} (\alpha '(t) - \beta '(t))dt}  = \int_{e^{ - 1} }^1 {s^n \left( {\beta '( - \log s) - \alpha '( - \log s)} \right)ds} $$ for all non-negative integer $n$, we have $
\beta '( - \log s) - \alpha '( - \log s) = 0$ and thus $
{\beta '(t) - \alpha'(t)}=0$ (see Lemma 2 in http://www.ctr.maths.lu.se/media/MATC12/2013ht2013/uniqueness.pdf). Consequently, $\alpha(t)=\beta(t)+C$ with some constant $C$.

Comment: Thanks, but how to deal with the case that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not differential?

Comment: consider making them different on a set of measure zero

Comment: Integrating by parts should simplify the problem

Comment: The question is - are linear combinations of $e^{-nt}$ dense in $C[0,1]$?. Note that this set is an algebra. By Stone -Weierstrass theorem it is dense in $C[0,1]$ if it separates points which is obvious.